# jQuery Add and Remove Classes When Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Help! I'm in the process of developing a site and I need my navbar links to change color when scrolling down the page. I want it to indicate what current part of the page the user is on. My code:

HTML

```
<nav class="fixed navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="linkone"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li class="linktwo"><a href="#posts">about</a></li>
        <li class="linkthree"><a href="#contact">posts</a></li>
        <li class="linkfour"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="scroll scroll1>
    <h1>Scroll 1</h1>
</section>

<section class="scroll scroll2">
    <h1>Scroll 2</h1>
</section>

<section class="scroll scroll3">
    <h1>Scroll 3</h1>
</section>

<section class="scroll scroll4">
    <h1>Scroll 4</h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
}
.navbar{
  background-color: #333333;
}
.darker{
  color: #000000;
}
.scroll{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.scroll1{
  background-color: #555555;
}
.scroll2{
  background-color: #666666;
}
.scroll3{
  background-color: #777777;
}
.scroll4{
  background-color: #888888;
}
```

jQuery/JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > ('scroll1').height()) {
    $('.linktwo').addClass('darker');
    $('.linkone').removeClass('darker');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > ('scroll2').height()){
    $('.linkthree').addClass('darker');
    $('.linktwo').removeClass('darker');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() > ('scroll3').height()){
    $('.linthree').addClass('darker');
    $('.linktwo').removeClass('darker');}
});
```

aaaannnnddd the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpdbd8vy/1/)

for the life of me I can't figure out why the links aren't changing color at the right times. It could be something as simple as the call function. Please Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of just piggy backed of your code to make it work the way you wanted. You had some syntax errors. Missing the period when querying classes in your jQuery and missing a quote in the HTML

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll1 = $('.scroll1').offset().top;
  var scroll2 = $('.scroll2').offset().top;
  var scroll3 = $('.scroll3').offset().top;1
  var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  $('a').removeClass('darker');
  if (docScroll > scroll1 && docScroll < scroll2 && docScroll < scroll3) {
    $('.linktwo a').addClass('darker');
  } else if (docScroll > scroll1 && docScroll > scroll2 && docScroll < scroll3) {
    $('.linkthree a').addClass('darker');
  } else if (docScroll > scroll1 && docScroll > scroll2 && docScroll > scroll3) {
    $('.linkfour a').addClass('darker');
  } else{
    $('.linkone a').addClass('darker');
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<nav class="fixed navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="linkone darker"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li class="linktwo"><a href="#posts">about</a></li>
    <li class="linkthree"><a href="#contact">posts</a></li>
    <li class="linkfour"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section class="scroll scroll1">
  <h1>Scroll 1</h1>
</section>

<section class=" scroll scroll2 ">
  <h1>Scroll 2</h1>
</section>

<section class="scroll scroll3 ">
  <h1>Scroll 3</h1>
</section>

<section class="scroll scroll4 ">
  <h1>Scroll 4</h1>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zpdbd8vy/5/

Comment: This somehow works in jsfiddle but not in my browser is there some kind of framework im missing besides jQuery or something? I copied all the code into sublime word for word, linked them (<link> and <script>), and linked jQuery, but the result is different.

Comment: @IsaiahKahler where in your markup did you put the script tag? You will need to put it right before the closing body tag.

Comment: thanks for the heads up but it doesn't work either way for me. Mayble if there was a "download this fiddle as a webpage" feature to jsfiddle.net then I could see

Comment: @IsaiahKahler yeah man.. as long as you include all the files (including jQuery) in the correct way it should work. So you must be doing something wrong. jQuery should be included before the script. Check to see if there are any errors in the console.